# Windows 10 upgrade - "The display is not compatible with Windows 10"

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, graphics-card, windows-10-upgrade

I'm trying to run the Windows 10 Upgrade Assistant but it says my display is not compatible:

[image]

I have a Gigabyte NVIDIA GTX 750Ti graphics card which says it is compatible with Windows 10.

I have tried uninstalling the NVIDIA drivers and running the upgrade tool but get the same problem.

Any ideas please? Thank you!

Comment: It's possible the screen you are using has a very low resolution. But even if not, I recommend simply doing a clean installation because upgrading usually results in degraded performance and incompatibilities.

Comment: Thank you, my resolution is  1680 x 1050 which seems to be okay with Windows 10. Also can I do a clean install without a Windows 10 CD key?

Comment: The Windows 10 installation allows you to use Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 keys to be converted to Windows 10 keys. You can also postpone the activation with no annoying side-effects. Find more information here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation

Comment: The error message refers to the Display, not the Display adapter, so it's the monitor, not your graphics card that it is moaning about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gigabyte NVIDIA GTX 750Ti graphics card should be compatibile with Windows 10, I have MSI GTX 750Ti card and do not have any problem.

Try to run `devmgmt.msc`, expand `Graphics adapters` and see, if you have some other adapter installed, like LogMeIn driver or some other VNC virtual display adapters.

If yes, uninstall them, reboot and run the wizard again.

Comment: You're a star, thank you so much! I think my question has been downvoted since people believe it's a monitor problem rather than a display adapter, but having removed my virtual display adapters I'm now running the update wizard without any problems :)